# Input search filter not working (React)

Tags: ajax, reactjs, filter

Have component that works with React, Redux and AJAX:

```
    class IncomeProfile extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          items: this.props.items || []

        }
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.IncomeListProfile();

      }
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ items: nextProps.items });
}

      filterList(event) {
        var updatedList = this.state.items;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item) {
          return item.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        this.setState({items: updatedList}); // now this.state.items has a value
      }

      render() {
        var elems = this.props.items;
        if (typeof elems == 'undefined') {
          elems = [];
        }
        //console.log(elems);
        return (
          <div>
            <table className='table'>
              <thead className='theadstyle'>
                <th>date
                  <input></input>
                </th>

                <th>
                  <input onChange={this.filterList} type='text' placeholder='keyword search'></input>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <input type='text' placeholder='amount search'></input>
                </th>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>Show archived</th>
              </thead>
              <div className='tbodymar'></div>
              <tbody >
                {elems.map((item) => (

                  <tr key={item.course_id}>
                    <td>{item.created_at}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.remark}</td>
                    <td>{item.income_amount}</td>
                    <td>more options</td>
                  </tr>

                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        )

      }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
      return {
        IncomeListProfile: () => dispatch(IncomeProfileList())

      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
      //var mystore = state.toJS()
      var mystore = state.getIn(['incomeProfileList'])['course_list'];

      //console.log(mystored.hh);
      var copy = Object.assign({}, mystore);
      return {items: copy.course_list};

    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IncomeProfile);
```

When I enter something in input, I get error Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, but console.log show's my state. What wrong with filter ? Where mistake? if I had right state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.items` only get populate after `componentDidMount`?
If so, and you want to set the items in the `state` too. You can use `componentWillReceiveProps` method to set the new props to you state.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ items: nextProps.items });
}
```

Comment: what I must put into (nextProps) ? please show full version, if you can

Comment: this.props.items = nextProps ? like this  componentWillReceiveProps(this.props.items) {
    this.setState({ items: nextProps.items });
}

Comment: it's a react life cycle method, like `componentDidMount`, when a component get new props this method will be invoked with the new props as the `nextProps` object that you can use.

Comment: works, but when I enter some word in input I get @Cannot read property 'state' of undefined@

Comment: console.log(this.state.items); - work only in render

Comment: this is something else, it's because `this` inside your function is not pointing to your component instance when it's invoked. you can solve this using arrow function like this: `filterList = (event) => { ...`

Comment: the rest of your function can stay the same. this is only thing you need to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134189/discussion-between-doron-brikman-and--).